# How to i can watching live tream facebook with access_token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, live

How to i can watching live tream facebook with `access_token`

I want to increase the live audience video on facebook with token code.
Mostly I did not find the live view API via the token

Answer (score 0):

There is no support or API end point to view a Live Stream by using Access token of user.

So, you can't increase live audience by using the access token.
It can only be increased by actual viewers viewing it.

Comment: How to with cookie ? i think cookie can do